# How do you make an access a hash in python?

Tags: python, hash

I know this question sounds very basic. But I can't find it using Google. I know that there are dictionaries that look like

```
o = {
  'a': 'b'
}
```

and they're accessed with `o['a']`. But what are the ones that are accessed as `o.a` called? I know they exist because I'm using optparse library and it returns an object accessible like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access dicts using the '.' unless you implement your own dict type by deriving from dict and providing access through the '.' notation by implementing the `__getattribute__()` API which is in charge for performing attribute style access.

See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Comment: I see. Okay thanks. Just wanted to make sure I'm coding in the best way. Just started learning python today and I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the variables as a dictionary in "new style classes".  I think you have to be a little careful though.

```
>>> class C(object): # python 2 code, inheriting from 'object' is automatic in 3
    a = 5
    def __init__(self):
        self.j = 90


>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{'j': 90}
>>> print c.j
90
>>> print c.a
5
```

notice that 'j' showed up in the dictionary and 'a' didn't.  It looks to have something to do with how they are initialized.  I'm a little confused by that behavior and wouldn't mind an explanation from a guru :D

**Edit:**

Doing a little more playing, it is apparent why they decided to go with the behavior above (but it is still a little strange

```
>>> class C(object):
    a = 5
    def __init__(self):
        self.j = 90
        self.funct = range # assigning a variable to a function

>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{'j': 90, 'funct': <built-in function range>}
```

I think it separates the class object (which would be the same for every class) with new class members (such as those initiated inside **init**).  If I now do

```
>>> c.newvar = 234
>>> c.__dict__
{'j': 90, 'newvar': 234, 'funct': <built-in function range>}
```

You can see it is building a dictionary!  Hopefully this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like `optparse` simulates an attribute interface to a hidden `dict`, but there's a standard library that does something sort of similar, if not really a dictionary:  [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields).  I can't speak to the other mechanisms presented here.

Answer (score 0):

`name.attribute` is *object access* in Python, not *dict access*

Answer (score 0):

`__getattr__` is the method you want to implement, along with `__setattr__`.  Here is a very simplistic example (no error checking, etc) that shows an object which allows both dictionary-style and attribute-style access:

```
Missing = object()

class AttrElem(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.items = kwds.copy()
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        result = self.items.get(name, Missing)
        if result is not Missing:
            return result
        raise KeyError("key %r not found" % name)
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        self.items[name] = value
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        result = self.items.get(name, Missing)
        if result is not Missing:
            return result
        raise AttributeError("attribute %r not found" % name)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'items':
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            self.items[name] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'AttrElem(%s)' % ', '.join(
                ["%s:%s" % (k, v) for k, v in self.items.items()]
                )
```

In use it looks like this:

```
example = AttrElem(this=7, that=9)
print(example)
example.those = 'these'
example['who'] = 'Guido'
print(example)
```

As you can see from the code `__getitem__` and `__getattr__` are both very similary, differing only in the exception that gets raised when the target cannot be found.